# How to print checkboxes according to total days?

Tags: php, mysql, row, tabular

I having problem to print out check box according to booth and total days.
Brief story: I have 4 booths, name A1, A2, A3 and A4. I want to let customer booking my booths.  Customer can choose which day they want to book.Sometimes the booths available to book for 7 days, sometimes 15 days. Now I want to display my booths according to total days, if booths available for 15 days, then it will display：

[image: Booth Availability Overview]

if available for 7 days, then it display only 7 checkbox each row.

In my database I store booth, totalDay and D1-D15 as single field.
How to print the above pattern in PHP?

**table structure**
[image]

Comment: give some idea about table structure. i mean pictorial presentation.

Comment: My table structure http://i.imgur.com/voUum.jpg

Comment: Have you even started to develop the php part? Would be very helpfull to see some code

Comment: yupe I did, but it only display booth, no days, suddenly they want me to put day, have no idea

Comment: My code segment: http://www.2shared.com/file/bhTlpPSt/get_chid_categories.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is something like this:

```
$booths = array("Jake", "Amir", "Lilly", "Foo");
$dayCount = 15; // show checkboxes for 15 days
foreach ($booths as $booth) {
    echo "Booth $booth: ";
    for ($day = 0; $day < $dayCount; ++$day) {
        echo "checkbox for day $day, ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to close the posts as soon as it is solved. (ie. Mark it as an accepted answer.)

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\bookingmonth\checkbox.php on line 4

Comment: Obviously since I don't know your data structure.